# php date to sql

Tags: php, sql

I want to store php date in sql but it store `1970-01-01 05:00:` instead of input datetime

This is html form

```
<input type="datetime" id="eventstart" name="txtEventStart" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('m/Y/d h:i:s');?>">
```

when data is sent using post

```
$date = $this->input->post('txtEventStart');
```

I convert string to date format using:

```
$date2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

It stores `'1970-01-01 05:00:00'`

I want to know what is the correct format for storing such type of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is giving you the wrong results because your date is in a format (`m/Y/d h:i:s`) that is not recognised by [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Instead, use [`date_create_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to convert it and output a date in the correct form for SQL. For example:

```
$date = '08/2019/19 10:23:41';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date)) . PHP_EOL;
echo date_create_from_format('m/Y/d h:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
1970-01-01 01:00:00
2019-08-19 10:23:41
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/g9h5B)

Answer (score 0):

'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' is not an acceptable format for PHP date function. Use Y-m-d H:i:s instead. More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

**Update**: For date input field use ISO date format Y-m-d or change input type to 'text'

Comment: the one you are suggesting is already tried. it shows '1970-01-01 05:00:00'

Comment: You must also use the same format for the 'datetime' input field. Or you can change the input type to 'text'.

Comment: dear  Aiden there is on need to use the same format, one format can be converted to other

Comment: Although I can see that the issue was in your strtotime function, I would like to mention that datetime input format is no longer supported by most browsers. If you would like to set a value for an input type of "date" you MUST use ISO format, m/Y/d format will not be displayed by date input field. This is demonstrated here: https://onlinegdb.com/BkiOV3t4r